# Why is alert.log not located in path indicated by BACKGROUND_DUMP_DEST in oracle 12c (12.1.0)

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

Just do this : 
`startup open;`

Then
`show parameter background_dump`

The result of the show command on my machine is : 
`/ora01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/rdbms/log`

So when I go to that location, there is no alert log there.

Then I went to 
`$ORACLE_BASE/diag/rdbms/<db_name>/<oracle_sid>/trace`
I found the alert log there.

So my question is why BACKGROUND_DUMP_DEST  not containing the proper path to the alert log ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BACKGROUD_DUMP_DEST` parameter specifies the path where debugging trace files for the background processes like `PMON`, `DBWn` etc.

> #### BACKGROUD_DUMP_DEST
>
> This parameter is ignored by the diagnosability infrastructure introduced in Oracle Database 11g Release 1 (11.1), which places trace and core files in a location controlled by the DIAGNOSTIC_DEST initialization parameter.

The alert logs, trace files are  found  in Automatic Diagnostic Repository (ADR) Home determined by `DIAGNOSTIC_DEST`.
`<diagnostic_dest>/diag/rdbms/<dbname>/<instname>`.

The alert log location is `<diagnostic_dest>/diag/rdbms/<dbname>/<instname>/trace/`.

> #### DIAGNOSTIC_DEST
>
> Derived from the value of ORACLE_BASE ($ORACLE_BASE). If the $ORACLE_BASE environment variable does not exist, then $ORACLE_HOME is used.

The following files are located under the `ADR` home directory:

Alert Logs

Trace Files

Core Files

Incident Files

Reference:[DIAGNOSTIC _DEST](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-BFE9648A-24D4-4717-8C33-21B0868401EE.htm)

Comment: Awesome thank you. Btw,  I just found that it's the same with `USER_DUMP_DEST`.